Laravel multitenancy or single database for saas
I am building a saas that will connect an specific ecommerce cms and show you a dashboard with a bunch of kpis and charts.
Each user will subscribe with laravel cashier and connect their shops, the laravel application will get the user shop data (orders, products, customers, etc) and show some charts and reports.
My question is, imagine the we get 100 users and each user connect their ecommerce with 30k products, 15k customers, 50k carts and 20k orders my tables (MySql) will be huge.
It is a better option to do this with multitenancy so each user has their own database with their own data? or single database where each orders, customers, products, etc tables will have an user_id and shop_id row?
PD: each user will be able to connect multiple shops

For huge data it is advisable to use separate databases let me explain with few points:
Pros of multiple database:

Performance: With separate databases, each user's data is isolated, which can improve performance as the database size grows.
Data Isolation: Multitenancy in a single database can lead to complexities in data isolation and security. It also has SPOF(Single Point of Failure).
Scalability: Separate databases offer more scalability options.

Cons of multiple databases:

Complexity in backup as there are multiple databases.
Cost will be higher comparatively

